# How to send private feeds from company's name through facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I want to send something like feed seen to direct user only (I know the mechanism how to do it), but from something like page. As I've understood only public feeds are accepted for pages. Is there any analog object, that could be associated with my company and that could be an author for private feeds, seen only for direct users?

Answer (score 0):

No, as indicated at https://www.facebook.com/help/352402648173466?in_context, even if you enable settings:

[image]

What you can do is narrow the audience by conditions(age, demographic...etc), post feed specify audience by user id is impossible:

[image]

My first thougth was send private message as the solution, unfortunately, as indicated at https://www.facebook.com/help/273376269375028/, what you can do is only

> send messages to people who've contacted you on your Page

Answer (score -1):

You are able to retrieve a page's feed by querying the following graph endpoint:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{group_id}/feed
```

Please see the following reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#feed

Posting to a feed requires you to have the access_token for that page, which can be retrieved by calling `/me/accounts` using the `access_token` of a user with admin privileges to that page.

Comment: `code`(
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Posts where the actor is a page cannot also include privacy.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 100
  }
})

Comment: `{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) Posts where the actor is a page cannot also include a target_id", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 200
  }
}`